# Mopa Bootstrap bundle failing to install

Tags: netbeans, composer-php, bundle

I get this error while trying to install the Mopa bootstrap bundle through command line:

> "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat" require
>   mopa/bootstrap-bundle ^3.0
>
> Error:
>
> installation failed reverting ./composer.json to its original content
>   mopa
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Im lost since I`m not getting any explanation of what failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So listen here, I have a solution for you. As I see that you are working with composer I'll teach you how to do it.

First you must change your "composer.json" file in your project, adding in "require" section:

```html
"require": {
    ...
    "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "*",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "*"
}
```

(NOTE: "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "*" is recommended to put as well when you use twbs).

And then add this repository in the json:

```html
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "version": "2.2.1",
                "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Save and finally, you should execute your composer update(dev) command.

Hope it works!